# Why the function into parent method will be declared twice?

Tags: php, function, class, oop, inheritance

[Here](https://3v4l.org/Y5KVq) is a simplified of my code:

```
<?php

class questions {

    public function index( $from = null ) {
        
        if ( $from != 'test' ) {
            return $this->test();
        }
        
        return 'sth';
    }
    
    public function test(){
        
        function myfunc(){}
        
        return $this->index(__FUNCTION__);
    }
}


class tags extends questions {

    public function index () {
        return parent::index();
    }

}

$obj = new tags;
echo $obj->index();
```

As you see in the fiddle, it throws this error:

> Warning: Declaration of tags::index() should be compatible with questions::index($from = NULL) in /in/Y5KVq on line 29
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare myfunc() (previously declared in /in/Y5KVq:16) in /in/Y5KVq on line 16
>
> Process exited with code 255

Why? Naturally `myfunc()` should be declared once. Since `test()` will be called once. So what the error says?

Anyway, how can I fix it?

Comment: You can only declare functions once. If you're going to declare it dynamically in code that may run multiple times, you should wrap it in a `if (!function_exists('myfunc'))` check.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yes I can do that check you mentioned. But I want to know why that function will be executed more than once? How the code will be compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$obj` is an instance of `tags`, and `tags::index()` does not have the `$from` argument.

So here's what happens when you call `$obj->index()`:

1. `tags::index()` calls `parent::index()` (which is `questions::index()`) without any arguments.
2. `questions::index()` receives no arguments, therefore `$from` is `NULL`
3. Since `$from` is not equal to `'test'`, it calls `$this->test()`. Keep in mind, that as far as PHP is concerned, `$this` refers to `$obj`, so an instance of `tags`. So `questions::index()` is actually calling `tags::test()` here.
4. `tags::test()` does not exist, so instead, `questions::test()` is called.
5. `questions::test()` defines the function `myfunc()` and returns `$this->index()` with the name of the current function (`'test'`). Again, keep in mind, that as far as PHP is concerned, `$this` refers to `$obj`, so `questions::test()` is actually calling `tags::index()` here.
6. `tags::index()` accepts no arguments, and calls `parent::index()` (or `questions::index()` without any arguments.
7. Since `questions::index()` is called from `test::index()` without any arguments, `$from` is once again `NULL` and we end up in a loop that crashes because the function `myfunc()` is now already defined.

If you remove the `myfunc()` function declaration, you'll see that you end up in an infinite loop.

Changing `test::index()` to accept a `$from` argument which is passed on to `parent::index()` will make this code work the way you want:

```
class tags extends questions {

    public function index ($from = null) {
        return parent::index($from);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you .. great analyse. Just can you show me an example of your last paragraph ?

Comment: And my last question: Do you know how can I handle `$other_arg`? The expected output is `sth`. https://3v4l.org/pIEr7

Comment: Well, like the warning says: `tags::index()` needs to have the same arguments as `questions::index()`. So you need to add `$other_problem` to the declaration of `tags::index()` as well.